# asp.net remove trailing slashes

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I got this code in my web.config

```
<rule source="(.*)/$" destination="$1" />
```

When I load some page www.example.com/page.aspx/, I got same page loaded but with messed up styles and pictures, and every link from that page is now www.example.com/page.aspx/somelink.apsx

Is something wrong with this rule?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do with the url rewriting. Can you post examples how the rewriting should be working?

Comment: when someone visit www.example.com/page.aspx/, he should be redirected to www.example.com/page.aspx (trailing slash is removed)

Comment: Are you using IIS? I'm pretty sure there is a predefined rule for that.

Comment: Yes, it is IIS, how that rule look?